# Is it possible to write a PEP 8 compliant, one-line, conditional expression that can do nothing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have the following code

```py
if condition_met:
    do_something()
```

Where I call `do_something` for a specific condition, but otherwise do nothing. I *could* condense it to one line with the following

```py
if condition_met: do_something()
```

But that wouldn't be PEP 8 compliant. I was hoping something like the following would work.

```py
do_something() if condition_met
```

But its a syntax error unfortunately. I tried the next, fairly silly, one-liner, but it too is a syntax error even though it's multi-line equivalent is valid.

```py
do_something() if condition_met else pass  # syntax error
...
if condition_met:
    do_something()
else:
    pass  # valid syntax
```

I've came up with the following one line expression that is PEP-8 compliant, or at least makes `flake8` happy.

```py
do_something() if condition_met else None
```

But the above isn't very pythonic and the multi-line equivalent makes even less sense than the one using `pass`. Is there a way to do nothing in a one-line expression while still being PEP 8 compliant?

Comment: As long as you are trying to adhere to PEP 8...maybe you should also consult [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) "There should be one--and preferably only one--obvious way to do it." which IMO is the 2-line `if` you started with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
 condition_met and do_something()
```

The short-circuiting behavior of `and` means `do_something()` is only invoked if `condition_met` is truthy (the result of the expression would be whatever `do_something()` returned in that case).

I'd personally recommend sticking to the two-liner, or even violating PEP8 and putting the two-liner on one line if you really *hate* two-lining it. Using `and` for flow control without the result of the whole expression being used is more ugly/confusing than the straightforward solution.

Comment: I agree, the extra line saved from using `and` isn't worth how obtuse the code becomes